# how to configure firewall between two machine?

Tags: firewall

I have two Ubuntu machines. I want to set a firewall configuration defining that 1st machine can communicate with the 2nd machine but the 2nd machine cannot communicate with the 1st one. So, what will be the firewall rule?

Comment: Every network communication must be two ways - so what you seem to want is not possible - maybe you can reword your question?

Answer (score 2):

Choose the port that you would use; for that, control which port are already used on your computers using `netstat`. Here is an example :

```
damadam@Pc:~$ sudo netstat -ntlp 
Connexions Internet actives (seulement serveurs)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Adresse locale          Adresse distante        Etat       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      657/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5195/cupsd          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      916/postgres        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1553/exim4          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10231/python3       
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      5195/cupsd          
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      1553/exim4
```

Now, choose a port not used (I would use the 89362 port for example). Use these commands :

- `sudo ufw allow out 89362` on the 1rst machine -> `out` allow to talk, but not to listen
- `sudo ufw allow in 89362` on the 2nd machine -> `in` allow to listen, but not to talk

NB : you can also choose to restrict communication using only tcp/udp, you just need to add it after the port number, like that (here is only tcp accept):

```
sudo ufw allow out 89362/tcp
```